# tax_glom() or merge_samples() inhibits downstream calls for sam_table() categories

Tags: r, phyloseq

I have data with OTUs representing fungal taxa I have discovered through metabarcoding of moths with ITS2 primers.
I have a `phyloseq` object with an `otu_table`, `tax_table`, and `sam_data`. In `sam_data` I have categories with all taxonomic levels of the sample (buttterfly).
I have merged the individual samples by a category in my `sam_data` called species.
This means that instead of having a bunch of samples where some samples are belonging to the same species, I now have a `phyloseq` object with much fewer samples, since the once who share species now are grouped together.

Code for merging:

`physeq <- phyloseq(OTU, TAX, META)`

`mergesamp_physeq <- merge_samples(physeq, "species")`

I have also merged the OTU table so that OTUs identified to be the same species are merged into one OTU:

`merge_physeq <- tax_glom(mergesam_physeq, "species")`

I now want to do a PCoA on this data using genus to colour the samples in my ordination, but the return shows me a PCoA without colour. I get no errors. See immage of [PcoA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQMDk.png) plot, script below:

`pcoa_bc = ordinate(merge_physeq, "PCoA", "bray")`
`plot_ordination(merge_physeq, pcoa_bc, color = "genus") + geom_point(size = 3) + ggtitle("PCoA")`

Does someone might now what has happened? It works fine before merging of samples and taxa.

EDIT:
My sam_data() does indeed get a lot of NAs after merging.
Identical column names is adressed as R by a warning, but it automatically renames my sample data headers with a "sam_" prefix, so that should be no issue.
I have solved this by phrasing my question differently in another post the whole issue with merging samples is resolved here: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74287436/sam-data-gets-transformed-into-nas-and-numerical-values-when-using-merge-samples)

Comment: Without an example of your data it is not possible to reproduce your problem; however, calling `merge_samples` without an appropriate  `fun` argument (the default is `mean`) may have resulted in NA values in your `sample_data`. Could you check this using `sample_data(mergesamp_physeq`)?

Comment: You may also be getting some issues from having identical column names in both your taxonomy table and your sample data. For example, if you were to call `psmelt` on this dataset, the columns from the sample data would get renamed from e.g. 'species' to 'sample_species'. If you then try to colour by species, it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved here: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74287436/sam-data-gets-transformed-into-nas-and-numerical-values-when-using-merge-samples)
The issue is with merging and the issue is more clearly stated in this post.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail to this answer? The link is helpful, but it's preferable that answers are as self-contained as possible.